# size of propertie on Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

How do I indicate the max size of a property on EA?

[image]

Is there a special field?

Maybe creating a data type with maxsize propertie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the tab right to "Notes": "Constraints"

[image]

My OCL isn't very good (IOW it might be incorrect). You can also use `Invariant` instead of OCL and use plain text.